# Angular 7 doesnt recognise a route named History

Tags: angular, routes, angular7

I have set up a basic Angular 7 app with default quickstart project settings.
I have a routes file defined as below:

```
//imports left out for brevity 

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '',   component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'Home',   component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'History',   component: HistoryComponent},
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true} )], 
exports: [RouterModule]
});

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I have added an import for my routing file to the 
    `imports:[]` section of my `app.module.ts` file and when i run `ng serve` and open up my browser and visit `localhost:4200/#/` and `localhost:4200/#/Home` the subsequent pages open up fine. But whn i try to visit `localhost:4200/#/History` it doesnt open and i get the error below:

[image: error when visiting localhost:4200/History]

When i change the route name to something else, it opens up fine. Im just wondering why History wont be recognised as a route by Angular?

**Edit:**

app.module.ts:

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
 import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

 /* Components */
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
 import { HistoryComponent } from './components/history/history.component';

 /* Routing Module */
 import { AppRoutingModule }   from './routes/app.routing.module';


 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 HomeComponent,
 HistoryComponent
 ],
 imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 AppRoutingModule,
 FormsModule,
 ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

`

app.component.ts:

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
```

app.component.ts

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
   title = 'app';
   }`
```

Comment: What do you think `useHash: true` does? Why did you add this to your configuration?

Comment: Also, the error message shows that what you tried is `history`, not `History`.

Comment: it lets me work with the /#/home /#/some_route_here routing scheme

Comment: even if you access the url with uppercase H, the error shows a small case h, i dont know why

Comment: can you add your `app.module.ts` file content and the main component where you place the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = 
[
   { path: '',   component: HomeComponent},
   { path: 'home',   component: HomeComponent},
   { path: 'history',   component: HistoryComponent}
];
```

Comment: it now detects history route, but why does it not detect History? when it detects all the other routes with capitalized letters?

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this:

```
 export const appRoutes: Routes = 
[
 { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
 { path: 'History', component: HistoryComponent},
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```